# how can I update user global fields in drupal services?

Tags: users, services

I have a user account, in this account I added a global fields. I am using [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module for consuming users data.

I am performing *CRUD* operations on users account. In this account, normal fields are updated successfully and one more global field also updated by using *PUT* method.

But some user's global fields are not updated.

Example:

[image]

In this, *first name* and *user email* fields are updated when I perform *PUT call*, but *check boxes* fields are not updated.

And in my request content body I wrote this code:

URL: http://drupal.com/services/user/100

```
{
"uid":"100",
"mail":"example@gmail.com",
"current_pass":"xyz",
"field_first_name": {
            "und": [
                {
                    "value": "xyz",
                    "format": null,
                    "safe_value": "xyz"
                }
            ]
        },
"field_status": {
            "und": [
                {
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

field status given 1, but field is not checked in user account.

Any suggestion?

Comment: The data you send is dependant on the widget you have specified for your fields. What widget(s) are you using? Also the user must have the `administer users` permission, or be logged in as their own account to update values.

Comment: widget type = boolean and these fields are global fields for users,and logged in as a user credentials.

Comment: The field type is boolean, the widget can be single on/off checkbox, etc...?

Comment: boolean and single on/off only,how can i take these checkbox value in drupal json input format for update PUT call.

Comment: Also try this field value: `field_status: { und: { value: 1 }}` - sometimes the delta value needs to be excluded, and sometimes the language code may need to be excluded - it is a bit unpredictable at times.