# How to set a checkbox using POST request with Services Module?

Tags: 7, commerce, services

I am trying to set a checkbox in a display using a post request by setting the value of the mark field to 1, specifically field_mark_as_discounted. But I can't seem to be able to achieve that. Note: The checkbox functions well when set manually. If anyone has come across this issue of setting a checkbox using post request please share.

Comment: long shot, but try setting it to `true`

Comment: tested it before; didn't work

Comment: one would think `1` should work, does your code work on other non boolean fields?

Comment: Are you **creating** new nodes, or are you **updating**?

Comment: yes the code works on all fields except the boolean and I am creating a new node, specifically a product display, which has the field.

Comment: is your field required or not? see my question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204946/updating-non-required-fields-via-services-json

Answer (score 0):

This probably is the JSON you need for that field when **POST**ing:

```
field_foo: { und: [ { value: 1 } ] }
```

Remember, the Services module is dependent on which widget you have selected on the *Manage Fields* page for your entity/bundle.

Comment: This is the same format that I have followed before with this field; moreover, I've checked the db and the field is saved correctly with same value as the node whose checkbox was manually clicked except in my case the node created using the post request does not have the checkbox clicked.